# Which Maven dependency to use for IBM PCOMM automation using Selenium, Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, ibm-pcomm

Can someone help me on what maven dependency to use for IBM PComm Emulator using selenium + Java for cucumber framework. any references of git or previously done any automation on this is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: @AdityaKumarSharma
can you please help here, i have seen some reference that you have used this before. thats really appreciated. thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <tn5250j>0.7.6.4</tn5250j>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vebqa</groupId>
            <artifactId>tn5250j</artifactId>
            <version>${tn5250j}</version>
        </dependency>
```

This works perfectly.